# New User: Welcome To MSE........

Tags: discussion, new-users

While posting this question I got good feeling. But why?? I think this is because while posting on META, you are doing something which may be significant for the site.

What is this site all about?? I think it is about learning Mathematics in a friendly environment where you can easily connect with the geniuses of a particular field.

Now, Everyone (or most of the users ) come on MSE with a question in mind which he/she has typed on google and saw that this similar question has been asked here. Suddenly he/she realise the scope of site by seeing the question/answers here and create a account. The game starts now.

With first question being asked, the user receive an average of $2-3$ downvotes and some comments like:

> Done now what??
>
> This is not a do my homework for free service website. (I won't mention name of those great men here who usually use these words).

What to say about this now?? There is a word which I often hear and read while chatting with some established users which is **RUDE**. The people come here for help, and if you make them realise that they do not know much maths they will leave you (Some highbrow people would now say that let them leave), if it is the case then how site would expand.

So, My question is that **Is there something which can be done to stop this??**. A friendly environment is not like this and specially for a new user.

Comment: "Is there something which can be done to stop this??" For a start, one could stop exaggerating the problem. "With first question being asked, the user receive an average of 2−3 downvotes" Really? On average first questions receive 2 to 3 downvotes. Do you have some data to back up this extraordinary claim?

Comment: Hopefully this - your first meta question - will be well-received, since we have no meta$^2$ site to discuss meta meta issues. Welcome to meta (where infinite regress is impossible,or is it?)

Comment: @Bill: I believe that it was established that the meta-operator is idempotent. :-)

Comment: Well, one should also hope, that such idempotence operators do not become metastatic...

Answer (score 11):

I remember when I joined this site, I did not receive any downvotes on my questions, even though my first question was actually 3 unrelated questions posted as one (not at all intentional).

It was actually quite good experience here (but I also read the basic rules and guidelines before asking more questions).

And even now, I can see questions lacking context, they are answered (maybe even I have done it) before they are closed and the person posting gets what they want in most cases. For subsequent use, obviously the person has to adhere to guidelines.

So the situation right now is good as is. The environment is as friendly (rare instances of exception may be there) as can be without degradation of quality of posts.